# cant add image in react getting an error Error: Cannot find module './undefined' when using require

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add image using `<img src={require(`../images/${book.cover}`)}></img>` but it is giving me an error Error: Cannot find module './undefined', I tried doing it without require using `<img src={`../images/${book.cover}`}></img>` but that int displaying the image either, no error but just an icon that appears when the image is not being displayed, somebody please help me resolve this. I have scoured the internet looking for a solution but no heed.
here is my code:

```
const { book, quantity } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <img src={require(`../images/${book.cover}`)}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <h2>{book.title}</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Category: {book.category}</li>
              <li>Author: {book.author}</li>
            </ul>
            <p className="button blue">${book.price}</p>
            <p>{book.description}</p>
            <button
              id={book._id}
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggle();

                this.AddToCart();
              }}
              className="btn btn-success"
            >
              Add to Cart
            </button>
```

Comment: share complete code how you are importing and in which folder you saved image?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this exact error in an image src require. It's thrown when the pass-in is undefined, which in your case is `book.cover`. Essentially it wants to set the source as an undefined link. That `./` is implied.

Consider conditional rendering with a `typeof` check to ensure that the image tag does not load if the cover does not exist.

```
if (typeof(book.cover) !== 'undefined') {
  return ( <img src={require(`../images/${book.cover}`)} /> );
} else {
// error handling here
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are building something like blog or Ecomm site you are storing img in a folder.

my img is inside upload/pic.png  upload is my folder where I am storing img

### Transfer your img folder or img to Public folder

### access

### img in .js FILE

```
<img src={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL`/uploads/pic.png} />
<img src={ process.env.PUBLIC_URL`/uploads/${this.props.data.postImage}`} />
```

### img in .HTML

```
<img src = '%PUBLIC_URL%pic.png'/>
```

read about file processed by

### webPack